# How to search for duplicate, unknown, strings in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am merging a couple different linux kernel branches, but I have already found that after adding changes from a git diff of a couple Kconfig files, that my base source code already had some of those configs in another directory's Kconfig file.

So, I am looking for a result/output similar to this:

> find . -name .git -prune -o -type f ( -name 'Kconfig*' ) -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n "$@"

...except, instead of searching for a known word or string entered at the end of that command, I need to **find duplicates within different Kconfig files, without knowing the string.**

**For example:** I added **config ARCH_VEXPRESS** and a lot more like it, to arch/arm/Kconfig, where it was in the 2nd branch... since it was missing there in my base branch. I later found that there were duplicates of many, because it already existed in arch/vexpress/Kconfig or another Kconfig.

So, does anyone know of a command or bash script that I can use to search all Kconfig* files for duplicates of "**config $@**" *without entering the $@ STRING*???

**I would like it to output/display the file names/locations, the duplicate string, and preferably the line numbers where they are both located as well.**

Comment: The `uniq -d` command will display the duplicate lines in its input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -name 'Kconfig' -print0 |
    xargs -0 awk '/^config/ { count[$2]++; files[$2] = files[$2] " " FILENAME":"FNR; }
                  END { for (keyword in count) {
                        if (count[keyword] > 1) { print keyword files[keyword] }
                        }
                    }'
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to upvote but thank you very very much! You saved me a lot of time and work, of having to go through and double check before I add a new config, or after I merge a full directory's Kconfig. Now I can just run that command, see if arch/arm/Kconfig contains the same as arch/arm/mach-msm/Kconfig or drivers/soc/qcom/Kconfig just like I asked! Genius! Plus that will help in the same way with sorting out the makefile diffs as well, with a minor tweak, as the needed files being merged are device specific but from an older kernel and stuff moves!!! Thanks a ton!!!